# KeyDown Event is not responding till any user control is clicked or setFocus implicitly?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

KeyDown Event is not responding till any user control is clicked or setFocus implicitly . I want to fire the key event after  the page loads , anytime.

I tried like :

```
   private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
             {
                 if (e.Key.ToString() == "Escape")
                   {
                        string uri = "/Views/Music/ArtistbyAlbum";
                        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
                   }
            }

        void LayoutRoot_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("hi");


}
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Subhen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you give focus to a control within the page you cannot get key events, that is essentially what having the focus means.  The control that has focus is the control which will receive key events.

In the code behind on the page use the OnNavigatedTo event and call the `Focus` method on the first control that can receive the focus (that is the first control that is visible, enabled and has `IsTabStop` value of true).

Another approach might be to set the page `IsTabStop` to true and call `Focus` on the Page itself.